# Getting Un Wanted Gallery Shortcode In The Page on Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, gallery

I have a custom Post Type and I am running a regular WordPress loop in `single-move.php` page to display the textual content of the page only. now while the post has an image gallery I am getting the Gallery Shortcode  in the page like `[gallery ids="16,14,15"]`

> [gallery ids="16,14,15"] In a world obsessed with slim and ......

Here is my code

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        $meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        the_post(); 
        echo '<section class="title-section">';
          echo '<div class="container text-center">';
          echo '<span class="icon-vlogo title-logo"></span>';
              echo '</div>';
          echo '<h3 class="text-center page-title">'. get_the_title().'</h3>';
       echo '<div class="container"><div class="hr"></div> </div>';
      echo '</section>';

    echo '<div class="container" style="padding:12px; ">';

    echo '<p class="p-paragraph" style="text-align:left">'. get_the_content().'</p>'; 

    echo '</div>';

        if ( get_post_gallery() ) {
                      echo '<div class="row" style="padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px;">';
     echo '<section class="title-section">';
          echo '<div class="container text-center">';
          echo '<span class="icon-vlogo title-logo"></span>';
              echo '</div>';
          echo '<h3 class="text-center page-title"> Check out Our Job</h3>';
       echo '<div class="container"><div class="hr"></div> </div>';
      echo '</section>';
        echo '</div>'; 
        echo '<div class="container">'; 
             echo '<div class="col-xs-12 xol-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">';
            ?>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide post-carousel" data-ride="carousel">


  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       <?php 
         add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery','wp_full_size_gallery' );
         $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
        remove_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery','wp_full_size_gallery' );
          foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src ) {
              echo '<div class="item">';
              echo '<img src="'.$src .'" alt="Vancouver Best Laser Center" />';
    echo '</div>';


          }
             }
           ?>
  </div>
```

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it to not see the array in the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All filters applied to the `'the_content'` hook (including shortcode rendering) are not applied when you call `get_the_content()`.

This is why you get raw shortcode from your content.

You could use `the_content()` instead, or use `apply_filters` directly in your template.

In other words, replace this line:

```
echo '<p class="p-paragraph" style="text-align:left">'. get_the_content().'</p>';
```

with either (preferred method):

```
echo '<p class="p-paragraph" style="text-align:left">';
the_content();
echo '</p>';
```

or alternatively:

```
echo '<p class="p-paragraph" style="text-align:left">' . apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) . '</p>';
```

To learn more about these functions, you may look at the documentation and source code at [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) and [`'the_content'` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)

Comment: Thanks for reply Iceable, I am geeing the images on the page like a wordPress native galley but I just need to get their URL

Comment: Then you could de-register the shortcode and re-register it for this template only so with a dummy callback so it doesn't display anything. Does that sound like what you need?